# How to run a setInterval that loops and tries a max of 10 times before breaking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following to try to reload on a connection drop:

```
setInterval(window.location.reload(), 1000);
```

My concern with this is that it could continue forever, ddos'ing my application.

How can I update the above to try at max 20 times before giving up and breaking?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a cookie, request parameter, or url hash to count how many cycles it's done so far, and stop at cycle N. BTW, this seems like a very strange thing to be doing; without context, I'd venture to say there's a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: *"...try at max 20 times before giving up..."* What do you mean by "giving up"? What would prevent a page reload from failing?

Comment: from breaking out of the 1sec reconnect loop

Comment: The reload is going to exit, how would the never interval be called when the page is refreshed?

Comment: How are you detecting a dropped connection?

Answer (score 2):

This makes me feel dirty, but you could update/extract the window hash with each refresh:

```
function hack () {
  var last = parseInt(location.hash.slice(1));
  if (last < 20) {
    window.location.hash = last + 1;
    window.location.reload();
  }
}

window.location.hash = 0;
setTimeout(hack, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is in an iframe so it might be better not to use a hash?

Comment: Yup. Though there may be better ways to do it if you have access to the parent window...

Comment: Do you have access to the parent window (good information to include in your question)? If so, you can simply place a counter there and refresh (and/or update the src) on the iframe as needed...

Comment: @rjz, note that you should probably use `setTimeout` here, not `setInterval`. Otherwise, once 20 times have passed, the check will continue to needlessly be run every second. That aside, I agree with your last comment. Should probably be the parent frame controlling this, not the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist some counter state from one page load to the next so you can know when 20 reloads have been done.  Your options are:

1. A hash value
2. A query parameter
3. A cookie value
4. Something stored in local storage

If you don't need this value to persist beyond just the reloads of this page, then options 1) and 2) are better as they are only as persistent as you need.  A hash value will not be sent to your server, but could interfere with other uses of the hash value.  A query parameter would be sent to the server, but any reasonable server will ignore query values it doesn't know and it won't interfere with anything else.  I'd probably pick a query parameter and have actually used one to avoid infinite redirection loops in some of my code.  You could implement option 2) like this:

```
function checkAutoReload() {
    var currentCnt = 0;
    var re = /(\?|&)(reloadCnt=)(\d+)/;
    var param = window.location.search.match(re), newURL;
    if (param) {
        currentCnt = parseInt(param[3], 10);
        newURL = window.location.href.replace(re, "$1$2" + (currentCnt + 1))
    } else {
        newURL = window.location.href;
        newURL += window.location.search ? "&" : "?";
        newURL += "reloadCnt=1";
    }
    if (currentCnt < 20) {
        window.location.replace(newURL);
    }
}

setTimeout(checkAutoReload, 1000);
```

Notice, there's no need for a `setInterval()` because a given page's code only runs once before it either reloads or finds that it is done reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Store the reloadCount in localStorage

[MDN DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

```
    var maxReload = 20;
    var reloadPage = function() {
        if (typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null) {
            console.log(localStorage.reloadCount);
            localStorage.reloadCount = 0;
        };
        var reloadCount = parseInt(localStorage.reloadCount, 10);
        console.log(reloadCount);
        if (reloadCount < maxReload) {
            reloadCount += 1;
            localStorage.reloadCount = reloadCount;

            // RELOAD CODE HERE
        };
    };

    // call reloadPage from your code
    reloadPage();
```